# How to reduce link time in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using LTO in MSVC increased our build time considerably.

Before:
Build Time (Release):  00:02:48.2022884

After:
Build Time (Release):  00:04:50.1647716

Is there any way to reduce the total link time necessary in MSVC (or in general)?

Comment: I doubt it.  You're asking the linker to do a lot of extra work, and the MSVC linker is relatively fast in my experience anyway.  But do you actually do a lot of release builds?  I only tend to do them late on in the development process, personally.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of work has gone into improving overall linker performance the past few releases, so VS 2019 is a good upgrade for this.

For your 'local' development builds, `/DEBUG:FASTLINK` can help by avoiding the need to coalesce all the pdbs into one. This doesn't help your overnight builds, but it make as a big difference in your iteration time.

In general the overall time to perform "Whole Program Optimization" / "Link-Time Code Generation" is going to scale by the size of the final EXE. If you have a 'large monolithic' EXE--I've seen some PC games get up into the 100MB+ range--it will take a lot longer than a smaller EXE with a few DLLs.

See:

- [Recommendations to speed C++ builds in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/recommendations-to-speed-c-builds-in-visual-studio/)
- [Linker Throughput Improvement in Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linker-throughput-improvement-in-visual-studio-2019/)
- [Improved Linker Fundamentals in Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/improved-linker-fundamentals-in-visual-studio-2019/)

Comment: The linker basically generates two things: the final EXE or DLL, and a PDB with all the symbols merged. Creating the PDB can take a fair amount of time, so what ``/DEBUG:FASTLINK`` is doing is creating a PDB that just points back to all the individual PDBs already created in the build. This lets you do debugging LOCALLY with the PDBs all in place and saves the time. If you are publishing the EXE/DLL for others to use, the PDB has to be fully completed which you can do with either a full rebuild or a special tool.